# Use swing controls in other class Java

Tags: java, mysql

**EDIT** : I am now able to access the `tableData` by making a `MainFrame.java` instance in my `Database.java` but it's not working. The rows is not added.

I am new to Java and still learning. I am making a desktop app with mySQL interaction. I have a `JTable` which is declared in `MainFrame.java` like so

```
public javax.swing.JTable tableData;
```

Then I have a `Database.java` which has all the methods if interacting to the database. Then in `Database.java` I have function

```
private void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    MainFrame mainframe = new MainFrame();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)mainframe.tableData.getModel();
    // resultSet is initialised before the first data set
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        String id = resultSet.getString("id");
        String name = resultSet.getString("name");
        model.addRow(new Object[]{id, name});
    }
}
```

Then on that function I want to access `tableData` JTable because I will append rows in there based from the `resultSet`. Is it possible? Or what is the best way?

Comment: You need to add the rows (data) to the [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), not to the Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to fetch the result set and update the tableData in MainFrame class only.

Also if you want to update this in Database.java class you need to have instance of MainFrame.java here. And would not be recommended

Answer (score 1):

best approach would be a book ^^

use the table model to access table data, best practice is to use `DefaultTableModel`

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

now you can easily add/remove data from your table by simply adding/removing data to your table model

now you can add your data to your table by querying your `ResultSet`

```
ResultSet rs; // i really hope you already have performed your query
while(rs.next() ){
    String str = rs.getString(...); //your Code here

    //now you can add your data to the model:
    model.addRow(new Object[]{str});
}
```

honestly - this is only a 10-line-tutorial, i think you have to do some more practise! but dont feel embarresed, i think you will learn quickly ^_^

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my code similar to what you said and still not working.  The row is not adding and I don't have error mssage.

Comment: did you use the constructor with tableModel as constructor? if you did, you can get your model by calling `DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) myTable.getModel();` so can be sure to use the right one...

Comment: i want to say sorry, my answer sounded quite rude - it wasn't meant to be this way, please excuse me!

Comment: haha it's ok. it doesn't sound rude :) Yeah I already did that. hmm you can check my code above I already updated it :)

Comment: hmm hmm - maybe your table model is not properly set up....
`DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableMode(new Object[]{"name", "id"}, 0);` this create a table model with two columns

Comment: hmm in your code you are creating a new table model right? What if I already have an existing table and I just want to add rows in it?

Comment: of course you use only **ONE** `DefaultTableModel` for **ONE** `JTable`! if you want to add data to **the one** `JTable` you just get the accoring `TableModel` directly from your `JTable` - you create all in all only **ONE** TableModel and **ONE** JTabel....

Comment: stupid question: is it possible, that your `ResultSet` is empty?! have you tried to fill the table with data from other sources (simply add some rows outside the `while rs.next()...`-loop?

Comment: I tried filling up the table with hard coded data in my MainFrame.java and it works . However in my case I am filling the table inside the Database.java

Comment: Tried moving the adding of rows outside rs.next() and not working either

Comment: It's working now. tried just moving the adding of rows in the MainFrame.java